# Open-source, on-premise image analysis library/service with gender and age estimation?

Tags: gratis, image-processing

I know there are paid solutions, including big providers like Google and Microsoft, that have Image Analysis APIs, but due to their big scale, I'd rather use a less robust open-source solution that I can install on my own servers and use it as I please.

I'm aware that [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) can be used to use known algorithms and packages, but those seem to require a considerable setup time. Are there any easily deployed libraries that I can run on my own server and that are able to estimate gender and age from an image?
I'm specifically looking to call this from PHP, but am flexible with that.